# Can I mock npm library when using Angular component?

Tags: angular, mocking

I have some component, that uses library to check what device is used.

Can I mock this library to return specific response when I'm locally developing my app?

I'm just using almost barebone Angular project, where importing module with my component.
For local testing, I just created page with header/footer, and my component:

```
<header>
<my-custom-component>
<footer>
```

Comment: Depends how that library is used. Are you using a component? A service? A directive?

Comment: The answer is yes, you can mock the parts of the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

To mock a module, component etc, you can use [ng-mocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/extra/quick-start).

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    MockModule(DeviceDetectionModule), // <- mocks a library.
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
  ],
});
```